# How to extract playlists (list of file locations) from iTunes using python

Tags: python, itunes, playlist

I want to point a python script to my iTunes directory and extract the playlist information. I believe playlist information is in a .ITL file? How can I do this using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1660) there should also be an xml file in the same location with the express purpose of making your music and playlists available. Try using one of pythons many xml parsers to get that information. For example, [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Answer (score 3):

The iTunes library xml file is in the same directory as the .itl file. The file is in Apple plist format, and Python's standard library has [a good parser](http://docs.python.org/library/plistlib.html) for it.

Comment: do you know what format the .itl file is in? I tried that library with the .itl file and it didn't work, even though it supports binary plist files